# Correcting the installed path in MacOSx

Tags: linux, software-installation, macintosh, which

I have installed a software in my MacOsX called Plumed as a prerequisite for another software called GROMACS. Process of installation for Plumed is pretty standard.

```
      ./configure  --prefix=Users/shashank/Downloads/plumed-2.2.3/ 
      sh sourceme.sh ## contains paths of library, kernal etc. I have tried modifying it.
      make && make install
```

After successful installation, when I checked installation path

```
        which plumed
```

it returns

```
    /Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib//plumed
```

You can clearly see the double slash. I believe it's a bug. Is there any way to correct this installed path ? Correct path should be :-

```
    /Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/plumed
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra slash isn't coming from the installed location. The extra slash doesn't have any actual effect; in fact, all of these are equivalent paths (i.e. different ways of writing the same filesystem location):

```
/Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/plumed
/Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib//plumed
/////Users////shashank////Desktop//////plumed-2.2.3///src////lib//////plumed
```

I'm pretty sure what's happening is that you have the directory in your PATH with a trailing slash, and `which` is just adding another slash when it lists the path. This isn't really a problem, but if it bugs you, check your shell startup files (~/.bashrc, etc) for where that directory is added to the PATH. You'll probably find something like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/"
```

Just remove the trailing slash, open a new shell, and it should be gone.

Comment: You are correct, there is a line in sourceme.sh which has the same path definition. Just slightly different `PATH="/Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/":$PATH` but changing `PATH="/Users/shashank/Desktop/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib":$PATH` dint change anything.

Comment: @VikasDubey: Did you open a new Terminal window? The new definition won't automatically reload in existing shells.

Comment: @gordan No, I didn't.